# Fresh ZFS encrypted Ubuntu 22.04.1 installation boots into BusyBox

Tags: system-installation, usb, 22.04, zfs, usb-installation

I installed Ubuntu 22.04.1 on a USB drive using the Ubuntu ISO and qemu. I encrypted the drive using ZFS during the installation process.

I can boot the USB drive using qemu, however when I restart my machine and I boot the USB from the BIOS, I am reverted to BusyBox after entering my encryption password.

If I install from the same ISO to the same USB using luks encryption, the USB successfully boots from BIOS.

There seems to be an issue with the ZFS encrypted Ubuntu install.

Can anyone assist?

**Here is a copy of my boot.log file.**

```
[  OK  ] Finished Set console font and keymap.
[  OK  ] Finished Create Volatile Files and Directories.
         Starting Userspace Out-Of-Memory (OOM) Killer...
         Starting Network Name Resolution...
         Starting Network Time Synchronization...
         Starting Record System Boot/Shutdown in UTMP...
[  OK  ] Finished Record System Boot/Shutdown in UTMP.
[  OK  ] Started Network Time Synchronization.
[  OK  ] Reached target System Time Set.
[  OK  ] Started Userspace Out-Of-Memory (OOM) Killer.
[  OK  ] Finished Load AppArmor profiles.
         Starting Load AppArmor profiles managed internally by snapd...
[  OK  ] Started Network Name Resolution.
[  OK  ] Reached target Host and Network Name Lookups.
[  OK  ] Finished Load AppArmor profiles managed internally by snapd.
[  OK  ] Reached target System Initialization.
[  OK  ] Started ACPI Events Check.
[  OK  ] Started CUPS Scheduler.
[  OK  ] Started Start whoopsie on modification of the /var/crash directory.
[  OK  ] Started Trigger anacron every hour.
[  OK  ] Started Daily apt download activities.
[  OK  ] Started Daily apt upgrade and clean activities.
[  OK  ] Started Daily dpkg database backup timer.
[  OK  ] Started Periodic ext4 Online Metadata Check for All Filesystems.
[  OK  ] Started Discard unused blocks once a week.
[  OK  ] Started Refresh fwupd metadata regularly.
[  OK  ] Started Daily rotation of log files.
[  OK  ] Started Daily man-db regeneration.
[  OK  ] Started Message of the Day.
[  OK  ] Started Daily Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
[  OK  ] Started Ubuntu Advantage Timer for running repeated jobs.
[  OK  ] Reached target Path Units.
[  OK  ] Listening on ACPID Listen Socket.
[  OK  ] Listening on Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack Activation Socket.
[  OK  ] Listening on CUPS Scheduler.
[  OK  ] Listening on D-Bus System Message Bus Socket.
         Starting Socket activation for snappy daemon...
[  OK  ] Listening on UUID daemon activation socket.
[  OK  ] Finished Uncomplicated firewall.
[  OK  ] Listening on Socket activation for snappy daemon.
[  OK  ] Reached target Preparation for Network.
[  OK  ] Reached target Socket Units.
[  OK  ] Reached target Basic System.
         Starting Accounts Service...
[  OK  ] Started ACPI event daemon.
[  OK  ] Started Run anacron jobs.
         Starting LSB: automatic crash report generation...
         Starting Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack...
[  OK  ] Started Regular background program processing daemon.
[  OK  ] Started D-Bus System Message Bus.
         Starting Network Manager...
[  OK  ] Started Save initial kernel messages after boot.
         Starting Remove Stale Online ext4 Metadata Check Snapshots...
[  OK  ] Reached target Login Prompts.
         Starting Detect the available GPUs and deal with any system changes...
         Starting Record successful boot for GRUB...
[  OK  ] Started irqbalance daemon.
         Starting Dispatcher daemon for systemd-networkd...
         Starting Authorization Manager...
         Starting Power Profiles daemon...
         Starting System Logging Service...
[  OK  ] Reached target Preparation for Logins.
         Starting Snap Daemon...
         Starting Switcheroo Control Proxy service...
         Starting User Login Management...
         Starting Disk Manager...
         Starting WPA supplicant...
         Starting ZFS file system shares...
[  OK  ] Started ZFS Event Daemon (zed).
[  OK  ] Finished ZFS file system shares.
[  OK  ] Reached target ZFS startup target.
[  OK  ] Finished Record successful boot for GRUB.
         Starting GRUB failed boot detection...
[  OK  ] Finished GRUB failed boot detection.
[FAILED] Failed to start Authorization Manager.
See 'systemctl status polkit.service' for details.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for Modem Manager.
[FAILED] Failed to start Dispatcher daemon for systemd-networkd.
See 'systemctl status networkd-dispatcher.service' for details.
[FAILED] Failed to start Power Profiles daemon.
See 'systemctl status power-profiles-daemon.service' for details.
[FAILED] Failed to start System Logging Service.
See 'systemctl status rsyslog.service' for details.
[FAILED] Failed to start Snap Daemon.
See 'systemctl status snapd.service' for details.
[FAILED] Failed to start Switcheroo Control Proxy service.
See 'systemctl status switcheroo-control.service' for details.
         Starting Wait until snapd is fully seeded...
[  OK  ] Stopped Power Profiles daemon.
         Starting Power Profiles daemon...
[  OK  ] Stopped System Logging Service.
         Starting System Logging Service...
[  OK  ] Stopped Snap Daemon.
         Starting Snap Daemon...
[FAILED] Failed to start Disk Manager.
See 'systemctl status udisks2.service' for details.
[  OK  ] Finished Remove Stale Online ext4 Metadata Check Snapshots.
[FAILED] Failed to start WPA supplicant.
See 'systemctl status wpa_supplicant.service' for details.
[FAILED] Failed to start Network Manager.
See 'systemctl status NetworkManager.service' for details.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for Network Manager Wait Online.
[  OK  ] Reached target Network.
[  OK  ] Reached target Network is Online.
[  OK  ] Started Download data for packages that failed at package install time.
[  OK  ] Started Check to see whether there is a new version of Ubuntu available.
[  OK  ] Reached target Timer Units.
         Starting CUPS Scheduler...
         Starting Tool to automatically collect and submit kernel crash signatures...
         Starting MySQL Community Server...
         Starting OpenVPN service...
         Starting Permit User Sessions...
[  OK  ] Started crash report submission.
[FAILED] Failed to start Accounts Service.
See 'systemctl status accounts-daemon.service' for details.
[  OK  ] Started LSB: automatic crash report generation.
[  OK  ] Started System Logging Service.
[  OK  ] Stopped Network Manager.
         Starting Network Manager...
         Starting Download data for packages that failed at package install time...
[  OK  ] Finished OpenVPN service.
[  OK  ] Finished Permit User Sessions.
         Starting Hold until boot process finishes up...
[  OK  ] Started Tool to automatically collect and submit kernel crash signatures.
[  OK  ] Finished Detect the available GPUs and deal with any system changes.
         Starting GNOME Display Manager...
[FAILED] Failed to start User Login Management.
See 'systemctl status systemd-logind.service' for details.
[  OK  ] Stopped User Login Management.
         Starting Load Kernel Module drm...
[  OK  ] Finished Load Kernel Module drm.
         Starting User Login Management...
[  OK  ] Started User Login Management.
[  OK  ] Started Unattended Upgrades Shutdown.
[  OK  ] Started Network Manager.
         Starting Authorization Manager...
[FAILED] Failed to start Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack.
See 'systemctl status avahi-daemon.service' for details.
         Starting Hostname Service...
[  OK  ] Started Hostname Service.
[  OK  ] Started Authorization Manager.
[  OK  ] Started Power Profiles daemon.
[  OK  ] Started GNOME Display Manager.
```

Comment: Is it the Ubuntu install on the USB or the Ubuntu install on an actual computer that won't boot correctly? If the latter, you probably messed up grub on that computer when you were doing the install (it's probably on the USB). Unfortunately I have no experience with encrypted computers.

Comment: @OrganicMarble It is the install on the USB that is booting into BusyBox.